# SwiftUI LazyHStack alignment

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way that the columns in this view could be aligned left? So that each row wouldn't necessarily be the same number of columns?

Here is how it currently lays out:
[image]

And here is the code:

```
struct SizeSelectorView: View {
@State private var selectedSize: String = "medium"

let test = ["small", "medium", "large", "xlarge", "xxlarge"]
let adaptiveColumns = [
    GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100))
]
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: adaptiveColumns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(test, id: \.self) { size in
                Text(size)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(selectedSize == size ? .black : .white)
                    .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                    .background(selectedSize == size ? Color.red : Color.gray2)
                    .cornerRadius(16, corners: .allCorners)
                    .tag(size)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedSize = size
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is there a better way to do this besides LazyVGrid? I'd like each row of items to fit/align to the leading edge and truncate to the next row once an item doesn't fit.

Like

"small" "medium" "large" Spacer()

"xlarge" "xxlarge" Spacer()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So that each row wouldn't necessarily be the same number of columns?

While you can set the number of columns a view occupies by using [`gridCellColumns`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/emptyview/gridcellcolumns(_:)), I suspect you don't want the views to occupy a *fixed* number of columns, and instead *flow* like multi-line text.

That is, by definition, not a `Grid`.

You need a different layout to achieve something like that. For example, the [SwiftUI-Flow](https://github.com/tevelee/SwiftUI-Flow) package offers a layout like that.

Usage example:

```
let test = ["small", "medium", "large", "xlarge", "xxlarge", "foo", "bar", "baz"]
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        HFlow {
            ForEach(test, id: \.self) { size in
                Text(size)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(selectedSize == size ? .black : .white)
                    .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                    .background(selectedSize == size ? Color.red : Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .tag(size)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedSize = size
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

You can also set the item spacing, row spacing etc.