# Grid Item should have Dynamic Height in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, grid, collectionview, lazyvgrid

I am making a clone app like **Notes** in SwiftUI. I want to show the notes in **LazyVGrid items** to have dynamic heights

Currently I am using a LazyVGrid with flexible columns to show exactly 2 items in a row but I want to have each item should have the height according to its content.

This is my code:

```
let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()),
               GridItem(.flexible())]
    
   var body: some View {

        ScrollView {
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, content: {
                
                ForEach(notesArray) { note in
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            Text(note.title)
                                .font(.poppinsSemiBold(size: 12))
                            
                            Text(note.description)
                                .font(.poppinsRegular(size: 10))
                                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                        }
                        .padding()
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .background {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    }
                    .frame(minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 300)
                }
            })
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
   }
```

And this code is returning this:

[image: code returns]

What I want here is the item below should start from exactly the same place where the top one ends, neglecting the spaces.

This is what I want:

[image: required]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to make something similar to what [this library](https://github.com/tevelee/SwiftUI-Flow) provides? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76633662/5133585

Comment: @Sweeper No, I don't want this. I want different heights, not different width

Comment: The swift package gives you a `VFlow` as well. Did you actually check out the first link?

Comment: @Sweeper now I have a proper look at the answer, He is using a library.

Comment: @Sweeper I need exactly 2 columns and I am unable to do this by that library.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. How about [this package](https://github.com/lukepistrol/MasonryStack) then?

Comment: @Sweeper it seems like this would work, let me implement this

Comment: By definition, a grid is laid out in rows and columns. It looks like you only want it laid out in columns. So how about using an ```HStack``` that holds two ```LazyVStack```?  You will just need to decide, how to distribute the items to the columns. If you were to do it the same way as before then all odd items would go in column 1 and all even items would go in column 2.